# Raid Controller for 6-8 Sata III Drives in RAID 10

Tags: raid

I just bought an MSI P67A-GD65 but it looks like the 4 SATA III ports are on completely different controllers so I can't have them on the same RAID array. This is a problem. Is there a way to somehow set up a single raid array on this board using the two controllers? ( I dobut it ).

If not how would you guys recommend I set up a RAID 10 for 6-8 1TB WD Blacks that are SATA III. Hot swapping etc is super useful but can't spend a fortune.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Can i rephrase the question "I have 6-8 SATA III harddrives. How do I set up a raid 10"?

Comment: Yes, of course. :)